# How to delete the double quotes?

Tags: vuejs2

[image]

I want to delete the double quotes for changing it into Json object for drawing the picture.but after using many ways, I still can't resolve the problem.

Comment: Update question with way you tried

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid JSON string
u cant use ' in json

they need to escaped double quotes \"

```
var x = [["{\"x\": 1}"]]
var json = JSON.parse(x[0][0])
```